# Profiling a ruby / ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, profiling

I am looking to understand conceptually what all goes in profiling a ruby or ruby on rails program (e.g. memory usage, speed of request dispatching, speed of connecting with external programs like DB) and what are the best tools (at a conceptual and fundamental level) that are available.

Comment: Thanks guys. However, I am looking at more of a conceptual overview of performance profiling and then a few ruby specific tools and tricks.
I have used new relic RPM, but that pretty much does a lot of things for you by itself. I am looking more from a learning perspective and hence would want to use the concepts myself using some basic tools.

Comment: Your comment seems to make the question vague and esoteric.  You want tools to profile ruby, but you don't want tools that are specific to ruby?
Looking at source code for OSS tools that do this  might help you get conceptual understanding you are looking for.  In particular look at the source of Joe Damato's tools I linked to in my answer.  Github links at the respective links.  The articles linked go in depth into the issues behind profiling.

Comment: Mark, what I am looking at is a 2 step process to understanding the ruby performance profiling:
1.) Generic concepts: objects in memory, GC, speed etc
2.) Ruby specific tools to apply these concepts.
The benefit that I am trying to seek as a result of these 2 steps is:
1.) Get a generic idea of how an application can be profiled for performance (not in depth - generic)
2.) Since I am comfortable programming with Ruby and using Rails, check out the implementation of these generic concepts in live applications and programs

Hope this makes it clearer!

Comment: And I must add here: I work on a Unix flavor - Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it helps, but I read somewhere article saying, that Java is the best profiler for Ruby on Rails applications. The idea was to run them on JRuby and use JProfiler or other Java profiling tools to profile your Rails application.
Another possibility that I know of might be the Relic RPM, commercial application especially for profiling Rails applications.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I suppose, by that logic, if you could get Rails running on IronRuby, you could then use some of the .NET profiling tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you program on a Mac, you might want to check out [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace).

I personally use linux at the moment, so I can't speak to it's worth, but I've seen it mentioned quite a few times in various Rails books.

It was originally developed by Sun to run on [Solaris](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/dtrace/index.jsp), but I believe it now comes pre-installed on Mac OS X Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Joe Damato's [memory-profiler for Ruby](http://timetobleed.com/memprof-a-ruby-level-memory-profiler/)

Also worth looking at is his [ltrace patch](http://timetobleed.com/extending-ltrace-to-make-your-rubypythonperlphp-apps-faster/)

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated many tools (memory-profiler, rb-prof...) , and finally used: [oink](https://github.com/noahd1/oink)